SCDF-Server Unauthorized to read metadata from my private registry(docker)
I'm using SCDF 2.11.x in k8s cluster.
I'm facing error while registering the app, error log like below :
[nio-9393-exec-1] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource Docker Resource [docker:my.private.registry:5000/my-image:0.0.4] because of HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: "{"details":"incorrect username or password"}<EOL>"

ImagePullSecret exitst in my scdf-server and skipper configmap.
And I add registry-configurations on scdf-server configmap like below:
   spring:
      output:
        ansi:
          enabled: NEVER
      cloud:
        deployer:
          kubernetes:
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            imagePullSecret: registry-key
            containerSecurityContext:
              runAsUser:
        dataflow:
          container:
            registry-configurations:
              default:
              #myregistry:
                registry-host: my.private.registry:5000
                disableSslVerification: true

Why scdf-server Unauthorized to read metadata from my private repository?
What should I do?  Thanks for your help.
I'm trying to use SCDF

How did you create registry-key ?
